# External Rails App Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

So I have a Wordpress site and I also have an Rails based Application Process for people to sign up to come to our organization. Is there a way I can have a login form on the Wordpress site somewhere and when they click login, it logs them in to the rails app? I'm using Restful Authentication on my rails app.

Thanks so much!

Comment: are you the one hosting the wordpress site? and do you have access to the html pages of the wordpress site?

Comment: Yes. I'm hosting everything: the wordpress site and the rails app. And I have access to everything.